# Web development strach vs framework

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, pdo, frameworks

What is wrong if:

1. I dont use framework just use php pdo and in pages I check if user is loged in.
2. On frontend I use simple jquery ajax that work with JSON that I get from php pdo files and then create HTML with jquery...
3. I simple dont use relation in mysql...

So many developers say that my code is bad but that app builded with my code work exactly the same as code builded with laravel...

So why to use laravel or some framework when my code work great with php pdo and jquery...

Comment: Are you mentioning web development scratch? vs Laravel Framework?

Comment: ex: Login with register done in 5 minutes. Makes thing easier for short

Comment: show me some example for user login regster in 5 min?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frameworks usually make things easier and faster to implement. Also, they are usually tested. So with a good framework you can save a lot of time. Also, you make the life of other developers easier, when you use common frameworks.

Furthermore, frameworks are usually maintained by a community and get updated frequently, so you have new features, without having to program them.

And some frameworks also allow plugins/extensions (usually 3rd party implementations), which you can use - again, without having to spend time implementing those.

And the last point I can think of, is that frameworks usually encourage some kind of application structure, so that you can extend your application easier in the future.

There is nothing wrong, when you write your own code, but it is just more work and takes more time and other developers might have a harder life.

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel Framework** have the following rather than you're using, (Not in a well defined order)

1. Eloquent ORM
2. Query builder
3. Application logic
4. Reverse routing
5. MVC Approach
6. Packaging System
7. Restful controllers
8. Naming Conventions
9. Migrations
10. Composer Build
11. Automatic pagination
12. Form request and More..

Once you get started working with frameworks you don't ask this question.